# Migration to Git LFS has not reduced repository size

Tags: git, monorepo, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

We have a giant git repository of about 40GB. It contains almost 25 years of development history and was migrated between multiple VCS.

Recently we've been having issues with the repo, so we're looking into reducing the size.

As there are 60 developers actively pushing into the repository, I created a fork to perform test runs of the actions that can reduce repo size.

The first step has been to migrate to git LFS. We have .pdf files in the repo and for a long time have committed .mdb files. The .mdb files are no longer in the repo, but are still in the history.

I've tracked .pdf and .mdb files in LFS:

`git lfs track '*.pdf'`

`git lfs track '*.mdb'`

Committed everything:

`git commit -a -m 'set up lfs'`

Then migrated everything, took about 8-10 hours:

`git lfs migrate import --everything`

Then I force-pushed everything, which took almost 2 days:

`git push --force origin master`

And then did some cleanup:

`git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all`

`git gc --prune=now`

I also performed housekeeping on the GitLab Server and cloned the repository into a new location afterwards.

But the repo (.git/objects) is still exactly the same size as before, with over 100GB of LFS data on top.

From what I've read, it's normal that the size of the objects stays the same immediately after the migration, but the cleanup should get rid of the files that were migrated.

Is LFS just not useful in our case? Is there anything I am missing for the migration? Any other ideas as to what the reason might be for this?

The next step would be to use `filter-repo` to try and get rid of some of the size.

If all else fails, we might just set up a new repository from the current working tree and just keep a backup of the history in case we want to look something up...

Comment: Make a new clone and check its size. Since you mention only the force-push of `master`, you can try the new clone with `-b master --single-branch`.

Comment: I did make a new clone after running "housekeeping" on the GitLab server and it was the same size.  (added this info in the OP as well)

Comment: If you only force-pushed `master`, `-b master --single-branch` is necessary. Otherwise, the other branches/tags with the old commits with big data are still fetched. Housekeeping may not work as you expect. The repository on Gitlab has many internal refs. Some are invisible to the users and others are not. They still refer to big data. It's normal that the size on the page does not shrink. The clone won't touch those internal refs. As long as the new clone with the LFS-managed branches has a much smaller size than before, the migration is successful.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense as I only commited the new gitattributes on master. :facepalm: If I were to set up LFS in that way on every single branch, would that mean my repo could actually shrink properly?
I assume that the 100GB from migrating master branch would at least partially be reused?
Cloning just the master gives me 10GB on the new repo, 40GB on the old one.